# Sync a MS SQL Database with a MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, centos

I'm working on a CRM running on a MS Server working with a MSSQL Database and now I have designed a new platform for the CRM on a linux server with a MySQL database.

I've already used MySQL Workbench to migrate my MSSQL database to MySQL. However I would like to automatically sync them once per day.

Is there any tool or script (preferably on PHP) available for this kind of job. Otherwise can you give me an idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you want is called replication.  Both SQL Server and MySQL support it.  Here are links to the info you need to read:

[MySQL Replication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql)

[SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017)